# Can I travel from India to USA through Heathrow airport?

Tags: transit, lhr

I want to travel to USA from India through Heathrow (UK) airport. When I travelled to USA from India on H4 visa. After that I got H1 approval and my change of status changed to H1. Then I returned back to India and now my H1 has expired.
If I want to travel to USA through Heathrow, is it possible or will I have any problems regarding change of status or not?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a valid US visa, you are [exempt](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no) from UK transit visa requirements.  You will need a valid, unexpired US H-1 visa to enter the US in H-1 status; approved I-539 and/or I-129 is not sufficient.